Python dict of indices from list
I have a list of N pairs of integers [(int1, int2), (int3, int4) ...], (or any immutable objects that can be used as dict keys). The list contains ~sqrt(N) unique items.
I want a dict where each element is a unique element of the input list, and each value is a list of indices of the element in the list.
eg
l = [(1,2),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(5,2)]
d = {(1, 2): [0, 1], (1, 3): [2], (1, 4): [3], (5, 2): [4]}

I can build this dictionary in the following way
def indices_dict(l):
    d = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if not e in d:
            d[e] = []
        d[e].append(i)
    return dict(d)

But I seems like looping over all the elements if not optimal.
How could I make this faster by using more builtin python or numpy functions ?

You could make this faster by using fewer builtin python functions.

If you need every index in the output dict, you cannot skip iterating over entire input. What size of input are we talking about?

did you check how fast is your code for your data? Maybe it doesn't need any optimizations. Your code seems OK. Eventually you can use return d without dict() because d is already a dict. And if you want to use something else then you can use collections.defaultdict with list as default value - and then you don't need to check if to add new element. But it still need to use loop. But with defaultdict you may put it in dict comprehension

Do you have very large data? Or do you have such small data but many times? Please add more details.

@Lesiak the list is about 10 million items.

And how many *different * items?

@nocomment if the list is of lenght N, there is order sqrt(N) unique items

As for me current code is OK and it doesn't need optimizations.
You can only remove dict() because d is already a dict
def indices_dict(l):
    d = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if not e in d:
            d[e] = []
        d[e].append(i)
    return d

If you want to learn something new then you can use special dictionary with default value - collections.defaultdict - and then you can use list as default value to skip if. But this will need dict() at the end to convert defaultdict to normal dict
import collections
 
def indices_dict(l):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        d[e].append(i)
    return dict(d)


You can shorten it up a bit using setdefault, but you are not going to get speed ups from using numpy or pandas because you still need to perform the grouping operations and move the data back into native Python objects.
def indices_dict(l):
    d = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        d.setdefault(e, []).append(i)
    return d

